# Where do I find the keys to the burning hut in the Hinterlands?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I found a burning hut in the Hinterlands with a locked door:

[image]

I looked around the area, but I couldn't find any keys nearby. This hut is also not part of a quest I found so far.

The location of the hut on the map is:

[image]

Where do I find the keys and how do I open that door?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a key; a rogue can pick the lock. My Herald is a rogue and opened the door; if you're not, try Varric.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lock mark on the map, then you will be needing an inquisition perk, in secret category, I think it is called fine hands something.